# map doesn't show on php, somethin wrong with my code, my browser or my localhost server?

Tags: leaflet

Irigation Map
    
    
    asset/css/gisstyle.css">

```
<script>
    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([-7.9807, 112.6363], 12);
    var marker = L.marker([-7.91847, 112.62634]).addTo(mymap);
    var marker2 = L.marker([-7.92102, 112.57931]).addTo(mymap);
    var marker3 = L.marker([-7.98886, 112.56592]).addTo(mymap);
    var marker4 = L.marker([-7.89178, 112.62308]).addTo(mymap);
    var marker5 = L.marker([-7.96047, 112.54695]).addTo(mymap);
    var marker6 = L.marker([-8.00649, 112.5733]).addTo(mymap);
    /*  var circle = L.circle([-7.94512, 112.6311], {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 700
    }).addTo(mymap);
    var polygon = L.polygon([
        [51.509, -0.08],
        [51.503, -0.06],
        [51.503, -0.047]
        ]).addTo(mymap); 

    var pointA = new L.LatLng(-7.91846, 112.62634);
    var pointB = new L.LatLng(-7.91850, 112.62632);
    var pointList = [pointA, pointB];

    var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointList, {
        color: 'red',
        weight: 3,
        opacity: 0.5,
        smoothFactor: 1
    });
    firstpolyline.addTo(mapid); 


    var popup = L.popup()
        .setLatLng([-7.94515, 112.63334])
        .setContent("Rumah Adzanil.")
        .openOn(mymap); */

    /*function onMapClick(e) 
    {
            alert("You Clicked at" + e.latlng);
    }

    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);*/

    var popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
     popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
    .openOn(mymap);
        }

    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);

    marker.bindPopup("<b>DATA SALURAN IRIGASI</b><br><b>ID</b>: 1<br><b>Jenis Saluran Irigasi</b>: Saluran Primer<br><b>Panjang Saluran</b>: 1245 <b>m</b><br><b>Koordinat Awal Hulu</b>: -7.9807, 112.6363<br><b>Koordinat Awal Hilir</b>: -7.9807, 112.6363<br><b>Dimensi (lebar x tinggi x tinggi muka air)</b>: 1245 <b>m</b> X 50 <b>m</b> X <b>35</b>m <br><b>Sketsa Dimensi</b>: 1245 <b>m</b><br><b>Kurva Debit</b>: 30 <b>m/det</b><br><b>Kawasan Pengairan</b>: Kelurahan Tasikmadu <br><b>Keterangan Kondisi</b>: Baik<br><b>Foto Bangunan</b>:<br>:<img src='img/primer1.jpg' width='150px' height= '80px'/> ").OpenPopup;

    marker2.bindPopup("<b>DATA SALURAN IRIGASI</b><br><b>ID</b>: 2<br><b>Jenis Saluran Irigasi</b>: Saluran Sekunder<br><b>Panjang Saluran</b>: 500 <b>m</b><br><b>Koordinat Awal Hulu</b>: -7.9807, 112.61776<br><b>Koordinat Awal Hilir</b>: -7.9807, 112.6363<br><b>Dimensi (lebar x tinggi x tinggi muka air)</b>: 300 <b>m</b> X 50 <b>m</b> X <b>35</b>m <br><b>Sketsa Dimensi</b>: 1245 <b>m</b><br><b>Kurva Debit</b>: 30 <b>m/det</b><br><b>Kawasan Pengairan</b>: Kelurahan Mulyoagung <br><b>Keterangan Kondisi</b>: Sangat Baik<br><b>Foto Bangunan</b>:<br>:<img src='img/sekunder1.jpg' width='150px' height= '80px'/> ").OpenPopup;

    marker3.bindPopup("<b>DATA SALURAN IRIGASI</b><br><b>ID</b>: 3<br><b>Jenis Saluran Irigasi</b>: Saluran Tersier<br><b>Panjang Saluran</b>: 500 <b>m</b><br><b>Koordinat Awal Hulu</b>: -7.98886, 112.56592<br><b>Koordinat Awal Hilir</b>: -7.9807, 112.6363<br><b>Dimensi (lebar x tinggi x tinggi muka air)</b>: 300 <b>m</b> X 50 <b>m</b> X <b>35</b>m <br><b>Sketsa Dimensi</b>: 1245 <b>m</b><br><b>Kurva Debit</b>: 30 <b>m/det</b><br><b>Kawasan Pengairan</b>: Desa Jedong <br><b>Keterangan Kondisi</b>: Sangat Baik<br><b>Foto Bangunan</b>:<br>:<img src='img/tersier1.jpg' width='150px' height= '80px'/> ").OpenPopup;

    marker4.bindPopup("<b>DATA SALURAN IRIGASI</b><br><b>ID</b>: 4<br><b>Jenis Saluran Irigasi</b>: Saluran Primer<br><b>Panjang Saluran</b>: 500 <b>m</b><br><b>Koordinat Awal Hulu</b>: -7.98886, 112.56592<br><b>Koordinat Awal Hilir</b>: -7.9807, 112.6363<br><b>Dimensi (lebar x tinggi x tinggi muka air)</b>: 300 <b>m</b> X 50 <b>m</b> X <b>35</b>m <br><b>Sketsa Dimensi</b>: 1245 <b>m</b><br><b>Kurva Debit</b>: 30 <b>m/det</b><br><b>Kawasan Pengairan</b>: Desa Langlang <br><b>Keterangan Kondisi</b>: Sangat Baik<br><b>Foto Bangunan</b>:<br>:<img src='img/primer2.jpg' width='150px' height= '80px'/> ").OpenPopup;

    marker5.bindPopup("<b>DATA SALURAN IRIGASI</b><br><b>ID</b>: 5<br><b>Jenis Saluran Irigasi</b>: Saluran Sekunder<br><b>Panjang Saluran</b>: 500 <b>m</b><br><b>Koordinat Awal Hulu</b>: -7.98886, 112.56592<br><b>Koordinat Awal Hilir</b>: -7.9807, 112.6363<br><b>Dimensi (lebar x tinggi x tinggi muka air)</b>: 300 <b>m</b> X 50 <b>m</b> X <b>35</b>m <br><b>Sketsa Dimensi</b>: 1245 <b>m</b><br><b>Kurva Debit</b>: 30 <b>m/det</b><br><b>Kawasan Pengairan</b>: Desa Kucur <br><b>Keterangan Kondisi</b>: Sangat Baik<br><b>Foto Bangunan</b>:<br>:<img src='img/sekunder2.jpg' width='150px' height= '80px'/> ").OpenPopup;

    marker6.bindPopup("<b>DATA SALURAN IRIGASI</b><br><b>ID</b>: 6<br><b>Jenis Saluran Irigasi</b>: Saluran Tersier<br><b>Panjang Saluran</b>: 500 <b>m</b><br><b>Koordinat Awal Hulu</b>: -7.98886, 112.56592<br><b>Koordinat Awal Hilir</b>: -7.9807, 112.6363<br><b>Dimensi (lebar x tinggi x tinggi muka air)</b>: 300 <b>m</b> X 50 <b>m</b> X <b>35</b>m <br><b>Sketsa Dimensi</b>: 1245 <b>m</b><br><b>Kurva Debit</b>: 30 <b>m/det</b><br><b>Kawasan Pengairan</b>: Desa Gondowangi <br><b>Keterangan Kondisi</b>: Sangat Baik<br><b>Foto Bangunan</b>:<br>:<img src='img/tersier2.jpg' width='150px' height= '80px'/> ").OpenPopup;
    /*circle.bindPopup("Wilayah Kekuasaan Mafia Pepi");
    /* polygon.bindPopup("I'm a polygon"); */

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(mymap);
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

Works on my PC, just copy paste the code into a text editor, save it as html and it should run. 
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Leaflet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>
    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([-7.9807, 112.6363], 12);
    var marker = L.marker([-7.91847, 112.62634]).addTo(mymap);
    var marker2 = L.marker([-7.92102, 112.57931]).addTo(mymap);
    var marker3 = L.marker([-7.98886, 112.56592]).addTo(mymap);
    var marker4 = L.marker([-7.89178, 112.62308]).addTo(mymap);
    var marker5 = L.marker([-7.96047, 112.54695]).addTo(mymap);
    var marker6 = L.marker([-8.00649, 112.5733]).addTo(mymap);
    /*  var circle = L.circle([-7.94512, 112.6311], {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 700
    }).addTo(mymap);
    var polygon = L.polygon([
        [51.509, -0.08],
        [51.503, -0.06],
        [51.503, -0.047]
        ]).addTo(mymap); 

    var pointA = new L.LatLng(-7.91846, 112.62634);
    var pointB = new L.LatLng(-7.91850, 112.62632);
    var pointList = [pointA, pointB];

    var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointList, {
        color: 'red',
        weight: 3,
        opacity: 0.5,
        smoothFactor: 1
    });
    firstpolyline.addTo(mapid); 


    var popup = L.popup()
        .setLatLng([-7.94515, 112.63334])
        .setContent("Rumah Adzanil.")
        .openOn(mymap); */

    /*function onMapClick(e) 
    {
            alert("You Clicked at" + e.latlng);
    }

    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);*/

    var popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
     popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
    .openOn(mymap);
        }

    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);

    marker.bindPopup("<b>DATA SALURAN IRIGASI</b><br><b>ID</b>: 1<br><b>Jenis Saluran Irigasi</b>: Saluran Primer<br><b>Panjang Saluran</b>: 1245 <b>m</b><br><b>Koordinat Awal Hulu</b>: -7.9807, 112.6363<br><b>Koordinat Awal Hilir</b>: -7.9807, 112.6363<br><b>Dimensi (lebar x tinggi x tinggi muka air)</b>: 1245 <b>m</b> X 50 <b>m</b> X <b>35</b>m <br><b>Sketsa Dimensi</b>: 1245 <b>m</b><br><b>Kurva Debit</b>: 30 <b>m/det</b><br><b>Kawasan Pengairan</b>: Kelurahan Tasikmadu <br><b>Keterangan Kondisi</b>: Baik<br><b>Foto Bangunan</b>:<br>:<img src='img/primer1.jpg' width='150px' height= '80px'/> ").OpenPopup;

    marker2.bindPopup("<b>DATA SALURAN IRIGASI</b><br><b>ID</b>: 2<br><b>Jenis Saluran Irigasi</b>: Saluran Sekunder<br><b>Panjang Saluran</b>: 500 <b>m</b><br><b>Koordinat Awal Hulu</b>: -7.9807, 112.61776<br><b>Koordinat Awal Hilir</b>: -7.9807, 112.6363<br><b>Dimensi (lebar x tinggi x tinggi muka air)</b>: 300 <b>m</b> X 50 <b>m</b> X <b>35</b>m <br><b>Sketsa Dimensi</b>: 1245 <b>m</b><br><b>Kurva Debit</b>: 30 <b>m/det</b><br><b>Kawasan Pengairan</b>: Kelurahan Mulyoagung <br><b>Keterangan Kondisi</b>: Sangat Baik<br><b>Foto Bangunan</b>:<br>:<img src='img/sekunder1.jpg' width='150px' height= '80px'/> ").OpenPopup;

    marker3.bindPopup("<b>DATA SALURAN IRIGASI</b><br><b>ID</b>: 3<br><b>Jenis Saluran Irigasi</b>: Saluran Tersier<br><b>Panjang Saluran</b>: 500 <b>m</b><br><b>Koordinat Awal Hulu</b>: -7.98886, 112.56592<br><b>Koordinat Awal Hilir</b>: -7.9807, 112.6363<br><b>Dimensi (lebar x tinggi x tinggi muka air)</b>: 300 <b>m</b> X 50 <b>m</b> X <b>35</b>m <br><b>Sketsa Dimensi</b>: 1245 <b>m</b><br><b>Kurva Debit</b>: 30 <b>m/det</b><br><b>Kawasan Pengairan</b>: Desa Jedong <br><b>Keterangan Kondisi</b>: Sangat Baik<br><b>Foto Bangunan</b>:<br>:<img src='img/tersier1.jpg' width='150px' height= '80px'/> ").OpenPopup;

    marker4.bindPopup("<b>DATA SALURAN IRIGASI</b><br><b>ID</b>: 4<br><b>Jenis Saluran Irigasi</b>: Saluran Primer<br><b>Panjang Saluran</b>: 500 <b>m</b><br><b>Koordinat Awal Hulu</b>: -7.98886, 112.56592<br><b>Koordinat Awal Hilir</b>: -7.9807, 112.6363<br><b>Dimensi (lebar x tinggi x tinggi muka air)</b>: 300 <b>m</b> X 50 <b>m</b> X <b>35</b>m <br><b>Sketsa Dimensi</b>: 1245 <b>m</b><br><b>Kurva Debit</b>: 30 <b>m/det</b><br><b>Kawasan Pengairan</b>: Desa Langlang <br><b>Keterangan Kondisi</b>: Sangat Baik<br><b>Foto Bangunan</b>:<br>:<img src='img/primer2.jpg' width='150px' height= '80px'/> ").OpenPopup;

    marker5.bindPopup("<b>DATA SALURAN IRIGASI</b><br><b>ID</b>: 5<br><b>Jenis Saluran Irigasi</b>: Saluran Sekunder<br><b>Panjang Saluran</b>: 500 <b>m</b><br><b>Koordinat Awal Hulu</b>: -7.98886, 112.56592<br><b>Koordinat Awal Hilir</b>: -7.9807, 112.6363<br><b>Dimensi (lebar x tinggi x tinggi muka air)</b>: 300 <b>m</b> X 50 <b>m</b> X <b>35</b>m <br><b>Sketsa Dimensi</b>: 1245 <b>m</b><br><b>Kurva Debit</b>: 30 <b>m/det</b><br><b>Kawasan Pengairan</b>: Desa Kucur <br><b>Keterangan Kondisi</b>: Sangat Baik<br><b>Foto Bangunan</b>:<br>:<img src='img/sekunder2.jpg' width='150px' height= '80px'/> ").OpenPopup;

    marker6.bindPopup("<b>DATA SALURAN IRIGASI</b><br><b>ID</b>: 6<br><b>Jenis Saluran Irigasi</b>: Saluran Tersier<br><b>Panjang Saluran</b>: 500 <b>m</b><br><b>Koordinat Awal Hulu</b>: -7.98886, 112.56592<br><b>Koordinat Awal Hilir</b>: -7.9807, 112.6363<br><b>Dimensi (lebar x tinggi x tinggi muka air)</b>: 300 <b>m</b> X 50 <b>m</b> X <b>35</b>m <br><b>Sketsa Dimensi</b>: 1245 <b>m</b><br><b>Kurva Debit</b>: 30 <b>m/det</b><br><b>Kawasan Pengairan</b>: Desa Gondowangi <br><b>Keterangan Kondisi</b>: Sangat Baik<br><b>Foto Bangunan</b>:<br>:<img src='img/tersier2.jpg' width='150px' height= '80px'/> ").OpenPopup;
    /*circle.bindPopup("Wilayah Kekuasaan Mafia Pepi");
    /* polygon.bindPopup("I'm a polygon"); */

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(mymap);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`